# Linking 3 Flutter Projects in One Flutter Project

Tags: android, ios, flutter, mobile-application

There are 3 Flutter Projects with me.

1. Flutter Project for Business Directory
2. Flutter project for Job Portal
3. Flutter project for LMS

I need to link these three flutter projects in one flutter project.

https://ibb.co/hy9zdz9

In this image you will see the job portal banner, when user click on the post ad, the Job Portal Project shoudl be visible in the same app.

I need to know the task is possible to do it, if it is possible, how to do it?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "linking" the projects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If each Flutter project is a SEPARATED app, so there's no way you can link them together because, well, it is obvious 3 different apps. But if you use each one as a PACKAGE, or you can call it a module for your only main app, they can connect together. You can modify a little bit about those three and make them as PACKAGES, it is possible to link them together.

If you do this, you can add them in `pubspect.yaml`. I did this one time, a module for leaderboard and a module for game. Link them like this:

```
dependencies
    game_package:
        path: ../game_package
```

Good luck.